# Configure SOA Extension for Jdeveloper 12c

Tags: oracle, soa, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware, oim

I have installed version 12c of OIM, OAM, SOA, Weblogic using Oracle Middleware Quick Start Installer. But when I installed version 12c of Jdeveloper I get to know that I have to install it with soa 12c quick installer then only I can be able to use Jdeveloper for SOA workflow development. Any idea how can I use the Jdeveloper now as SOA is already installed in my system using the Middleware quick installer.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into the same problem now.

Comment: No not able to figure it out till date

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the SOA workflow development in JDeveloper was to use the SOA Quickstart installation and not the other OIM/Middleware or Jdeveloper installers.